# How many n square can fit into a square of side N

Tags: geometry, optimization

Suppose we have n small squares of equal sizes that has area w.
Suppose we have a fix square S of area A such that for area A, one area w < area A.

If square S's area A, length, and width are given, 
and if the n small square length, width and area w is given,
and if n small square has to be placed in area A such that n small square has to be space equally, 
then I want to know how many n small square I can placed into square S?
A simple formula.
This type of problem came from an engineer question.

Space equally means:

Suppose I have small square A, B, C, D.
If I place A and B inside square S, the distance between them is d.
If I place C inside square S, I want the distance between B and C to be e such that e=d.
If I place D inside square S and it is underneath A, I want the distance between A and D to be f, such that e=d=f.
I will repeat pattern into Square S is filled.

Furthermore, What if I replaced the n small square, with n small circle or rectangle.
But for now let just focus on n small squares.
IS there a area in mathematics that explore this problem?

Comment: Not clear what "has to be space equally" means, especially in the variants with circles. Depending on the interpretation, this could be anything from a trivial problem in arithmetic, to an open problem on the frontiers of Mathematics. Websearch "Geometric Junkyard" to get some idea of what it out there.

Comment: I find the problem statement very hard to read, but I take it that http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/squinsqu/ would not fall under “equally spaced”. I wonder why someone would specify the area, width *and* hight of a square, where any of these three would suffice. I also wonder whether the small squares are assumed to be aligned with the large one.

Comment: David, have you abandoned this question? Do you have any reaction to what has been posted here? Was my answer at all useful?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that all the squares are aligned (that is, each side of each square is vertical or horizontal), that the small squares are not to overlap (except possibly at their boundaries), and that the centers of the small squares are meant to form a square lattice (this takes care of the "equal spacing" requirements.

The small squares have area $w$, so side length $\sqrt w$. The big square has area $A$, so side length $\sqrt A$. So the number of small squares we can put in a row is $[\sqrt A/\sqrt w]$, where $[x]$ means the greatest integer not exceeding $x$ (e.g., $[\pi]=[3.14159\dots]=3$). The number of rows we can get is also $[\sqrt A/\sqrt w]$, so the number of small squares is $$[\sqrt A/\sqrt w]^2$$

For example: if $A=10$ and $w=2$, then $\sqrt{10}/\sqrt2$ is between 2 and 3, so $[\sqrt{10}/\sqrt2]=2$, and we can fit in $2^2=4$ squares.

Comment: I am using your formula. I am not certain if it makes sense. I wrote a python script based on your formula, so I will present the solution:
Let L = 193.64, so A = 37500.
The length of a smaller square is 60,
thus I can place 4 squares of size 60 x 60 inside a square of A = 37500, such that each square is equally distance from one another.

Comment: The few answer I have arrived at from your formula seems to make sense. So your answer was helpful Thanks you. From your logic, I think I can obtained how many n circle of each size, can fit inside a square of size A.

Comment: I don't see why you can't fit 9 $60\times60$ squares inside a square of area 37500.